# Dynamic Validation but with Columns

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to do a dynamic data validation list using row 5 and adding columns as data is added to those columns. So I have googled and found lot's of offset formulas that are designed to offset on rows but my data is in columns (D5, E5, F5, G5, H5, etc ....). 
I tried adapting this formula but it doesn't give me what I want:

```
=OFFSET('Borrower Database'!$D$5,0,0,COUNTA('Borrower Database'!$5:$5),1)
```

I want my list to read from the columns on row 5 and dynamically grow as I add more names to the next columns.

Can anyone tweak this formula for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there :) Look at `OFFSET` function definition. In your formula `[height]` is swapped with `[width]`. Corrected formula:

```
=OFFSET('Borrower Database'!$D$5,0,0,1,COUNTA('Borrower Database'!$5:$5))
```

Comment: I have this formula in my data validation list as the source and it works great BUT, if $D$5 is deleted the validation box gets a REF error where $D$5 is and causes the validation to fail when I add new entries. Do you know any way around that?

Comment: You can [create a named range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) and refer to it in `Source` of `Data Validation`.  Or, how I often do it, I create a new sheet where I store my data validation values. It keeps the main sheet clean and I can hide the data validation sheet in case I don't want users to accidentally remove something.